# Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int32'

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to set my datetimepicker to todays date and a selected. Then set the second picker to tomorrows date and a selected time. My problem is it won't increment the days then though I call that method. How can I change this to add a day and keep the desired time?

If I remove the Convert I get an error: The best overloaded method match for `System.DateTime.DateTime(int, int, int, int, int, int)` has some invalid arguments

```
RadDateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 17, 30, 0);
RadDateTimePicker2.SelectedDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)), 5, 30, 0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day`

```
new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day, 5, 30, 0);
```

`AddDays` method returns a new `DateTime`, you can't convert it to `int`.Just use [`Day`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get the day in your new datetime.

**Update:** @UlugbekUmirov is right about his comment, in order to fix that issue you can try:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime first = new DateTime(now.Year,now.Month,now.Day, 17, 30, 0);
DateTime second;
if (now.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, now.Month))
{
     if(DateTime.Now.Month == 12)
           second = new DateTime(now.Year+1, 1, 1, 5, 30, 0);
      else
           second = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month+1, 1, 5, 30, 0);
}
else
{
    second = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day+1, 5, 30, 0);
}
RadDateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = first;
RadDateTimePicker2.SelectedDate = second;
```

Comment: Ok I really appreciate it! Why do no examples show this they just add .AddDays(1)?

Comment: Oh ok! Makes sense I looked up several and none used .Day. Thank you!

Comment: What will happen if today is Jan'31?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov I am not 100% sure on that answer.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov may I ask why sorry for not knowing.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos Imagine today is 31.01.2014. `DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day` = `(01.02.2014).Day` = `1`. Then you construct `new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 5, 30, 0)` - giving you `01.01.2014 05:30:00`.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
DateTime today    = DateTime.Now.Date + new TimeSpan( 0 , 17 , 30 , 0 ) ;
DateTime tomorrow = today.Date        + new TimeSpan( 1 ,  5 , 30 , 0 ) ;

RadDateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = today    ;
RadDateTimePicker2.SelectedDate = tomorrow ;
```

Comment: Can't say I have seen this way before, I am assuming the head numbers aka 0, and 1, are the days incremented?

Comment: You might try reading the documentation on [`TimeSpan` constructor overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Now` can change between calls, it's better to do the following:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
RadDateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = today.Add(new TimeSpan(17, 30, 0));
RadDateTimePicker2.SelectedDate = today.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 5, 30, 0));
```

Comment: That make sense for this because they will never need precise timing. Thank you!

Comment: does this code doing the same thing with OP's code ? he creates a new DateTime specifying hour and minute as 17:30, but you are adding 17 hour and 30 minute from now.

Comment: @Selman22 I add to `Today`, not `Now`. `Today` has zeroed time - it is equivalent to `DateTime.Now.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is very verbose (as is the sample code in your question).

Why not this:

```
RadDateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.AddHours(17.5);
RadDateTimePicker2.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.AddHours(29.5);
```

Or, if you want to be clearer about the time component of the second line, you could use this instead:

```
RadDateTimePicker2.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(5.5);
```

Comment: Well I thank you for your help and input as with most thing in code there are many different ways to do things. I will upvote and I appreciate you showing me a simplified way of doing things.